# What's causing a process to start at startup?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, autostart

I've got a problem:

A while ago, I installed a piece of software called `wii-u-gc-adapter`, and when I run it, I can plug my GameCube controller in to my Linux machine desktop computer to play games. This works great.

I must have taken some advice at some point in time to put somewhere in my computer an instruction to run this process at startup.

I bring this up because when I turn my computer off, it hangs for one minute 30 seconds waiting for this process to end.

When I run `./wii-u-gc-adapter` myself, I then manually kill it. But at some point in installing it, I told my system to run it.

The program is listed in `usr/local/bin`, which doesn't surprise me.

Here is the end of my `$pstree`

```
        ├─whoopsie───2*[{whoopsie}]
        ├─wii-u-gc-adapte───2*[{wii-u-gc-adapte}]
        ├─wpa_supplicant
        └─xdg-permission-───2*[{xdg-permission-}]
```

In `htop` I see the following when I filter for wii:

[image: htop filtered for wii]

When I shutdown my computer, I have to wait for one minute 30 seconds, and when I press F2 I see this message:

`A stop job is running for Wii U Gamecube Adapter`

I'd like to clean up this loose end. I usually document what I do when I modify a file, but I don't think I did here, so I'm having a hard time finding where I made a change that causes this program to run on startup.

[Some progress here - edit 1]

```
~$ ps j 1045
   PPID     PID    PGID     SID TTY        TPGID STAT   UID   TIME COMMAND
      1    1045    1045    1045 ?             -1 Ssl      0   0:00 /usr/local/bin/wii-u-gc-adapter
```

So the parent process of 1045 is PPID 1, i.e. it looks like someone told systemd to start this process. I would like to take this process off that list.

[ more progress here]

Found a gamecube.service file by going to /etc and using ag to search for it.

```
systemd/system/gamecube.service
2:Description=Wii U Gamecube Adapter
8:ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/wii-u-gc-adapter
```

I'd like to completely remove this service.
[Third edit] I am following this answer: https://superuser.com/a/936976

[Fourth edit] Following the procedure from superuser, after finding that the parent process was indeed systemd with ps j, this problem is now resolved.

Comment: Please add your solution as an answer down below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution:

1. Find process name in pstree
2. Find process in htop, get PID from there
3. Use command `~$ ps j [PID]` to find the PID of the parent process
4. If the PID is 1, then it is being started by `systemd`
5. If it is started by systemd, use [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/936976) along with the information you got from step 1 and step 2 to totally remove the process from `systemd`'s list of what to run on start up.